# Search all Exchange 2013 mailboxes via powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange

I have a long list of email addresses/domains and I need to check if any of our mailboxes have received emails from them.

I can find how to search using the GUI but that will take too long.
Found powershell commands for Exchange 365 but nothing for 2013.

A simple output to a file in the format...

```
address/domain,Yes|No
```

is sufficient. The list of addresses/domains will have to be read from text file.

Any ideas/examples?

---

EDIT 1: The following when run as the domain admin works...

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery from:<text> -estimateresultonly
```

but gives me a list of all mailboxes in the following format:

```
RunspaceId       : f21e1a-42c-4b7-559-90c643f18
Identity         : <blah/blah>
TargetMailbox    :
Success          : True
TargetFolder     :
ResultItemsCount : 1
ResultItemsSize  : 26.71 KB (27,350 bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after much googling, this will get me there. I need to wrap it in a loop but there are plenty of examples for that.

```
    [PS] C:\>$t = (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | 
                Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery from:@gmail.com -estimateresultonly  | 
                measure-object -Property ResultItemsCount -Sum).Sum

    WARNING: The Search-Mailbox cmdlet returns up to 10000 results per mailbox if a search query is specified. To return more than 10000 results, use the New-MailboxSearch cmdlet or the In-Place eDiscovery & Hold console in the Exchange Administration Center.

    [PS] C:\>echo $t
    30312
```

The good thing is that the SearchQuery will handle partial addresses so that makes it easy.

I'll update this answer once I have the full script.